# 13.10 Networking restart - wifi icon

Tags: wireless, networking

I'm wondering how can I bring back the wifi taskbar icon after the following command is executed:

```
service networking restart
```

Normally, that icon would be present to help us switching the available wifi networks quickly. However, if for any reasons one will restart the networking service - the icon will dissappear and won't come back. What app should I start to get it back?

Thanks,
Jane

Answer (score 0):

You can start the NetworkManager applet with the 'nm-applet' command.

```
$ nm-applet
```